# How to force some sort of "confirm before closing" option in Kate editor?

Tags: confirmation, kate

I very often work with a lot of files opened in Kate. Then, when closing one of the files I am editing, I unconsciously press alt+F4 and then Kate happily closes ALL the opened files I was editing and leaves me again shouting and performing another resilience test with the keyboard and the hardware in general...

Isn't there a way to force Kate to show me a "confirm before closing" dialogue when I try to close more than one file at a time, like for instance Firefox does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Session chooser** could be a workaround. All the files you had open before closing down Kate will be reopened.

To enable this function, go to `Settings` - `Configure Kate`. Under `Application` - `Sessions` choose one one of this behaviours:

- Load last used session
- Manually choose session

Then, you need to save the session manually (only the first time you use this session). Do that under `Sessions` - `Save Session as`. When you reopen that session later and make changes to that session (open files, close files), this changes will be saved automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work, unless you have manually saved the session (session > save session) before, which you would have to be remembering and doing consciously all the time, with every added document...

Comment: @Mmm... I am going to try, and I'll give you the green point in case it works (I have not yet enough reputation to upvote, which I tried anyway). Thanks very much!